# Automatically translate a set of C constants to C++ strongly typed enum

Tags: python, c++, c, parsing, clang

We have a top-level C library header file which contains a set of constants
(and also C functions or course), e.g.:

```
const int32_t Sample_FooFoo = 1;
const int32_t Sample_FooBar = 2;
const int32_t Sample_BarFoo = 3;
const int32_t Sample_BarBar = 4;

int API_Function_BarbarbarFooFoo_1();
int API_Function_BarbarbarFooFoo_2();
...
```

The idea is to provide also a C++ wrapper for this header file for convenience: i.e., it just wraps a common group of functions into classes, exceptions to handle errors, all nice and shiny..

However, the problem we have stumbled upon is how to translate a set of C constants into appropriate strongly-typed enum ? Like the one above should be translated into:

```
enum class Sample : int32_t 
{
    FooFoo = 1,
    FooBar = 2,
    ...
};
```

Doing this manually essentially violates DRY paradigm which is not so nice and shiny anymore..
Perhaps there is some automatic way to do this ? For instance, by writing a python script which would parse C header file and translate each group of constants (maybe propertly annotated) into a corresponding C++ enum ?

Comment: While not being exceptionaly complex, the C syntax is already hard to process with a simple script: what about multi-line comments which could contain data close to what you want to process? And IMHO doing it manually does not violate the DRY principle: DRY says that final code should not contain repeated blocs and there will be no repeatition here.

Comment: Rewriting code involves manual work. How you go about it isn't important, only the end result.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [XMacro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

```
#define SAMPLE_ENUMS \
  X(FooFoo, 1) \
  X(FooBar, 2) \
  X(BarFoo, 3) \
  X(BarBar, 4)

#if __cplusplus

enum class Sample : int32_t 
{
  #define X(NAME,VAL) NAME = VAL,
  SAMPLE_ENUMS
  #undef X
};

#else

#define X(NAME,VAL) const int32_t Sample_## NAME = VAL;
SAMPLE_ENUMS
#undef X

#endif
```

I suggest adding `static` to C variant to avoid problem when linking multiple translation units due to multiple definitions.

Comment: +1 for an elegant idea, this will be definitely a way for internal development code.. also learned about X-macros. Yet, for our purpose this won't be an option: imagine you have a top-level header file of some C++ library (say OpenCV) defining the constants in such a cryptic way, also intelliSense most likely won't work here. I think the only way would be to do some postprocessing of a header file (during the initial project config), e.g. generating C++ variant enum from a C variant somehow..